# Multiply rolling window with an array (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a dataframe df1 consisting of 5 rows and an array x:

```
x=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

Timestamps  A
01:00       1
02:00       2
03:00       3
04:00       4
05:00       5
```

How can I multiple array x with df1.rolling(4) and get the sum of all products in each line? Seems like rolling command does not have the multiply function. My expected output:

```
Timestamps  A          
01:00       NaN
02:00       NaN
03:00       NaN
04:00       1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 4*4 = 30
05:00       2*1 + 3*2 + 4*3 + 5*4 = 40
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.dot` with `rolling.apply` to do this:

```
>>> df["rolled_A"] = df["A"].rolling(4).apply(np.dot, kwargs={"b": x})
>>> print(df)

  Timestamps  A  rolled_A
0      01:00  1       NaN
1      02:00  2       NaN
2      03:00  3       NaN
3      04:00  4      30.0
4      05:00  5      40.0
```